# Why is my CSS animation transition not working

Tags: css, animation

The transition should take 2.5 seconds, however the elements are being styled immediately instead.

```css
#members {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.member-card {
  background: grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.member-card.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="members">
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
    <div class="member-card fade"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The elements will be styled immediately because there is no intermediate rendering frame where the fade class does not exist. Either use CSS animations or use JS to add the fade class after the first paint is done.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. You could post this as an answer as it solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: can try this: https://wowjs.uk/

Comment: @ryanvb92 Consider that done: I've added sample codes for the two options I proposed, hope they help.

Answer (score 1):

To further extend on my comment, the reason why the transition is not firing is because there is no intermediate state when the page the rendered/painted, that the `.fade` class is not present. Therefore the browser "shortcircuits" to the final state. If you want an entry transition, you can try one of the two tricks:

### Option A: Use CSS animation

Define a fade-in animation for your element. Remember to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to ensure that the final animation state is persisted.

```css
#members {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.member-card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 2.5s ease-in forwards fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    background: grey;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    background: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="members">
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
  <div class="member-card fade"></div>
</div>
```

### Option B: Use JS to add the fade class after paint

Alternatively you can also use JS to add the fade class. The trick is to add the class "fade" after the first paint. This can be done by using either `window.setTimeout(..., 0)` or using [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). I prefer the latter because it explicitly waits for the next repaint:

```js
// Use requestAnimationFrame to wait for first paint
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.member-card').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add('fade');
  });
});
```

```css
#members {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.member-card {
  background: grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.member-card.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="members">
  <div class="member-card"></div>
  <div class="member-card"></div>
  <div class="member-card"></div>
  <div class="member-card"></div>
  <div class="member-card"></div>
  <div class="member-card"></div>
  <div class="member-card"></div>
</div>
```